# Does an internal hash digest in a message strengthen an outer digest?

Tags: cryptography, hash

A message digest is being used to verify that a message is the intended one.

By how much would bundling a hash digest with contents to form the message increase the difficulty of collision and preimage attacks against the message?

For example, to encode:

```
message = data . hash1(data)
message_hash = hash2(message)
```

To verify message using message_hash:

```
check(hash2(message) == message_hash)
data = message[:-digest_size]
check(hash1(data) == message[-digest_size:])
```

`hash1` and `hash2` could be completely different types of hash functions.

My reasoning for this was that any attack would have to break both hash functions - faking the outer digest would require constructing a message with a valid inner hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the outer hash algorithm is broken, the inner hash could help, but you have to consider how likely that scenario is with a well respected algorithm.

If the outer hash is so small that a brute force attack is feasible, the inner hash wouldn't help much at all. Instead of finding a message with the same hash, the attacker would have to find a message plus inner hash with the same outer hash, which pretty much amounts to the same thing.

So make the hash as large as you can, and concentrate on making sure there are no back doors in the rest of your system. 64 bits is probably just about OK unless you are anticipating a government or major corporation taking an interest in breaking your hash.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposal has something reminds me of [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac). This is a construction that allows one to create message authentication codes, keyed hashes if you wish.

However, I don't see the point of using 2  hash functions. Pick a one of the standard ones that have resisted attacks so far and go with it. If you assume one of them will get broken, why use it in the first place? SHA-2 or any of the final candidates for the SHA3 competition should be fine if you want strong security, more info here: http://ehash.iaik.tugraz.at/wiki/The_SHA-3_Zoo.

Comment: I have a constraint on the outer digest - it should be as small as possible. I thought that perhaps this idea would make up for the decreased strength.

Comment: Your digest size is fixed by the hash function you use. However, when you create hashes with symmetric primitive (i.e. not with asymmetric crypto), you can do a hash truncation: just take the last `n` bits. At the receiver side, do the same and see if your results match up. Of course, this reduces the strength of your hash digest.

Answer (score 1):

In some situations, the inner hash *may* make the task more difficult for the attacker, but not necessarily. For instance, if you use MD5 for both hash functions, then a collision for the inner hash would also imply a collision for the outer hash, given the iterated structure of MD5.

So adding the inner hash function will not necessarily *increase* resistance to collisions and preimages. On a pure theoretical point of view, it may actually *decrease* resistance, although this is quite improbable, especially if the hash functions are secure (but if the functions are secure, then the construction is pointless). On a more practical plane, this double hashing increases computational work load (more CPU, and possibly bigger code -- hence more L1 cache usage -- if the two functions are not the same). So my advice would be not to do that. Instead, use a single "believed secure" hash function such as SHA-256. The hash function will not be the biggest weakness in your application (or, more precisely, if the hash function *is* the biggest weakness in your application, then you are a programming god and/or [Donald Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)).

As an illustration, [SSL/TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246) uses MD5 *and* SHA-1 simultaneously as an attempt to resist weaknesses on either of the two functions. But the newer [TLS 1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) version switches to SHA-256 only.